PyQt6 override QTableWidget "select all" functionality with custom widget
I'm trying to build a custom watchlist widget using QTableWidget. By default, in the top left corner, if you press the empty box, it will select all items in the table. I want to replace this empty box with my own custom widget to add a QComboBox dropdown. Is this even possible? If so, how can I build this?

Example of what I'm trying to build. Clicking the corner box should open a dropdown that has various things

I already tried to override the selectAll() functionality to do other actions but I'm unable to replace the entire section with a new custom widget
Code
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QApplication, \
    QTableWidgetItem, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout

class CustomWatchlist(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomWatchlist, self).__init__()

        self.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        
        self.header_labels = ['Symbol', 'Mark']
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.header_labels)
        
        self.data = {'MSFT': '100.0',
                     'AAPL': '205.5',
                     'QQQ': '350.0'}
        
        for index, symbol in enumerate(self.data):
            row_position = self.rowCount()
            self.insertRow(row_position)
            self.setItem(index, 0, QTableWidgetItem(symbol))
            self.setItem(index, 1, QTableWidgetItem(self.data[symbol]))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    
    main_window = QMainWindow()
    main_window.setMinimumWidth(200)
    main_window.setMinimumHeight(200)
    
    central_widget = QWidget()
    main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
    main_window.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
    
    table = CustomWatchlist()
    
    main_layout.addWidget(table)
   
    main_window.show()
    app.exec()


Access the "corner button" with self.findChild(QAbstractButton), disconnect its clicked signal and connect it to the function that shows the popup.

@musicamante is there a way to replace the QAbstractButton with a QComboBox instead of only modifying the clicked signal?

No, it's created internally. But you could just create the QComboBox with the table as parent, then override the table resizeEvent and, after calling the basic implementation, use setGeometry() for the combobox based on the positions and sizes of each header.
